# xslt: set asterisk as default param value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need filter results by param 'year'. If param 'year' is not set I shouldn't filter results. Is it possible to set asterisk as default param value? Or I need construct xpath dinamically, or use xsl:if?

```
<xsl:param name="year" select="*"/>
...
<xsl:template match="albums">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="album[year=$year]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I know that by default xslt processor tries to evaluate it, but if I set

```
<xsl:param name="year" select="'*'"/>
```

xpath doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing your **xsl:apply-templates** to this

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="album[$year = '*' or year=$year]"/>
```

Alternatively, try changing the param to this

```
<xsl:param name="year" />
```

Then you can write this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="album[not($year) or year=$year]"/>
```

Comment: I will use your alternative way. Thank you!